# How to handle 32bit unicode characters in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I have a NSString containing a unicode character bigger than U+FFFF, like the MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF symbol ''. I can create the NSString and display it.

```
NSString *s = @"A\U0001d11eB";  // "AB"
NSLog(@"String = \"%@\"", s);
```

The log is correct and displays the 3 characters. This tells me the NSString is well done and there is no encoding problem.

```
    String = "AB"
```

But when I try to loop through all characters using the method

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

everything goes wrong.

The type **unichar** is 16 bits so I expect to get the wrong character for the musical symbol. But the length of the string is also incorrect!

```
NSLog(@"Length = %d", [s length]);
for (int i=0; i<[s length]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"  Character %d = %c", i, [s characterAtIndex:i]);
}
```

displays

```
    Length = 4
      Character 0 = A
      Character 1 = 4
      Character 2 = .
      Character 3 = B
```

What methods should I use to correctly parse my NSString and get my 3 unicode characters? 
Ideally the right method should return a type like **wchar_t** in place of **unichar**.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *s = @"A\U0001d11eB";
NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
const wchar_t *wcs = [data bytes];
for (int i = 0; i < [data length]/4; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%#010x", wcs[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0x00000041
0x0001d11e
0x00000042
```

(The code assumes that `wchar_t` has a size of 4 bytes and little-endian encoding.)

`length` and `charAtIndex:` do not give the expected result because `\U0001d11e` 
is internally stored as UTF-16 "surrogate pair".

Another useful method for general Unicode strings is

```
[s enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])
              options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
           usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", substring);
}];
```

Output:

```
A

B
```

Comment: This perfectly answers my question. Thank you so much Martin!